# How to assign more than 1 partition to a kafka consumer

Tags: c, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, librdkafka

I have created kafka consumer in c and created a topic with 10 partition, when i tried to read data using consumer it is only reading from 2 partitions and then says no more messages.
I tried using both the methods i.e subscribe and assign but none of them works.
How should i assign all 10 partition to a single consumer, Is this is the correct way of assigning partition to consumer?
I have build custom consumer using this repo https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/consumer.c
And modified line number 173 and 180 of above repo with below lines so that i can consume from all partition. But it is still not working.

```
for(int partition_number = 0 ; partition_number < 10 ; partition_number) { 
    rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_add(sub_list,topic[i],partition_number); 
}                                   
rd_kafka_assign(consumer,sub_list);
```

Comment: Is this related to your question? [GitHub Issues - How to consume multiple partitions in a single consumer?](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/970)

Comment: Actually i tried to add partition using rd kafka_topic partition_list add() but that is also only reading from 2 partition not from all 10.

Comment: @Suraj Please [edit] your question to add clarification or requested information. Don't use comments for this purpose. It is difficult to answer your question based on a vague description of your code. You should add some example code to the question in form of a [mre].

Comment: Do you have data in all ten partitions?

Comment: Yes data is in all 10 partitions

Comment: Why are you assigning a list rather than subscribing to the whole topic?

Comment: @OneCricketeer i tried to subscribe to whole topic also but that is also having same issue. And in that case it is only reading from partition 0 or 1. Is this is the wrong way to assign partition?

Comment: Please post more information like your topic describe output, how did you create it exactly, please  issue console-consumer with --property print.partition=true

Comment: Topics are automatically created if not present, and talking about kafka-console-consumer so it is perfectly reading from all partitions

Comment: Can you share your code? According to the documentation in subscribe() it will ignore the partition setting and just subscribe to the whole topic, did you try the example as it was written?

Comment: Yes I tried the example as it is written just changed few lines that i have provided in code block in question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run your example as it is without changing its logic, it using `subscribe()` with consumer group, your change to `assign` function instead of subscribe is breaking the logic... please update what happens after using the exact example, just change topic names.
With using `subscribe()` it ignore partitions and subscribe to the whole topic with consumer group and kafka control logic

---

Here is @edenhill assigner test, you might want to look in that code as well

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/tests/0051-assign_adds.c

Comment: Thanks it is working fine, but in between it is giving consumer no more messages error.

Comment: If the answer was useful to you , you should +1 it, regarding the no more messages please post new question with the information